# How to remove extra tab from a row in Hive export csv after decryption

Tags: hadoop, hive, hiveql, beeline

Facing issue while exporting data from hive :

Hive version :  2.6.5

Quality check in big query output error :
**Error message:** Too many values in row starting at position: 2121402186. Found 22 column(s) while expected 21

Step 1 : exported the data from hive into a csv using command :

```
beeline -u $HIVE_JDBC_URLL --silent=true --outputformat=tsv2 --showHeader=false --silent=true -e " SELECT
      a.abc,
      a.mno,
      a.xyz,
     CASE
      WHEN a.xyz LIKE '%=%' THEN DECRYPT(STRING(b.decryptid), STRING(xyz))
      ELSE a.xyz
     END as xyz,
    FROM
      db.a a
    LEFT JOIN
      b
    ON
      (a.abc = b.def)" > "/tmp/abc.csv"
```

Step 2 : upload this file to big query to see if data loaded correctly .

Bigquery fails with above error message. My guess is, after decryption, it is adding one extra tab in a couple of rows from the entire file. Please suggest a way to find out that extra tab from the file so that this can be automated using ansible.

Also possible way, to double quote the fields while extracting from hive to csv so we might be able to avoid the extra tab ?
please suggest what should be added to the beeline command to do so ?

OR

How do I validate number of columns in each row ?

Comment: There are configuration options in the BigQuery transfer tool that you can use to ignore a certain number of invalid rows, handle jagged rows etc. I suggest you look into them.

Comment: @BenWatson , bigquery is used only to understand if the data is good in this scenario. The end user will be using data from hive. Please let me know if you have any ideas ?

Comment: I understand, my point is that the "error" is to do with the last column being blank in most cases and your BQ settings not handling that well.

Answer (score 1):

I the error was getting generated or an extra tab was getting added due to issues with hive export and I had to use regex_replace to solve it.

regexp_replace(a.xyz,'\t','') as xyz,